# Is there any way to dynamically align a div at the center always while scrolling up and down?

Tags: jquery, html, css

The div must be at the centre of the screen always while scrolling up or down.

```
<div class="col-md-6"
    <div id="align-dyna">
     some text here
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: make its position as fixed using css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.col-md-6 {
    height: 9000px;
}

#align-dyna {
   position:fixed;
   margin:25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="align-dyna">
    some text here
    </div>
</div>
```

Make your div as `position:fixed`